# Right click on cell and display modal window in Angular UI Grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Is there a way to display modal window when user right click on Angular UI grid cell? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to display modal window when user right click on Angular UI grid cell? Thank you.

#### Short answer: yes

In `columnDefs` for column write custom `cellTemplate`

#### Details:

```
columnDefs: [
    {
     displayName: 'SomeName', 
     field: 'name_obj',
     enableSorting: true,
     enableColumnMenu: false,
     cellTemplate: myCellTemplate            
  }
},
```

For example:

```
var myCellTemplate = 
                    '  <div class="grid-tooltip" tooltip="{{ COL_FIELD.name }}" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip-append-to-body="true">' +
                    '     <div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">' + 
                    '           <div layout="row">'+
                    '              <wm-check-box style="padding: 2px 10px;"  ng-model="row.entity.name_obj.isSelected"'+
                    '                       ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();grid.appScope.onSelect(row.entity.name_obj)" aria-label="selected ui-grid label" '+
                    '               ></wm-check-box>'+
                    '               <span style="white-space: nowrap;-ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;-o-text-overflow: ellipsis;text-overflow: ellipsis;overflow: hidden;"> {{ COL_FIELD.name }} </span>'+                        
                    '            </div>'+
                    '    </div>' +
                    '  </div>';
```

Check how I wrote `ng-click`. I used `wm-check-box` but you can write your own button or similar

---

Hope it will help you to start